# Any risks format Django project using format plugin in IDE?

Tags: django, pep8

What's the potential risks if I want to do the code format (PEP8) for an already existing, working Django project using format plugin in IDE, will it break the system? If it could, plz provide some examples, so I could try to avoid 'em. Many thanks.

Comment: what IDE you use ?

Comment: I use PyCharm, Sublime

Comment: I mean the auto format plugin tools, will they introduce some unknown errors into the system?

Answer (score 0):

All depend to plugin you want to add in your IDE! Pep8 is a python conventions help you to make a pretty python code source ( [you can read this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).
If plugin have bugs or not compatible with version of you ide it can crash IDE load not a system. Before add plugin you must read all comments on it !

Comment: What about the plugin for sublime?

Comment: If you uses sublime 3 or 2 don't paniq ! i have this plugin's installed and i use it !

Comment: i have this two plugin's installed: >>>>https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20PEP8%20Autoformat and https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Pep8%20Lint

Comment: all of them are sure !

Comment: Thanks, rakwen, I've also installed the plugin, what I really want to know is that If I format the whole project, will it break the system? PS: the old system is in really bad format, but it's working.

Comment: you don't have to format it ! the way is that sublime 3 have many plugin's like linter if linter detect that you code structure is wrong it mark error and you have to read error to adapt you code. Those plugin's help you to write python in pep8 convention ! it not modify your code ! mark my answer if help you.

Comment: I mean the auto format plugin tools, will they introduce some unknown errors that may break the system?